# Apache Web Server Architecture

Tags: apache

I am looking for how apache web server hands over the new request to already forked thread ? How the one thread that accept connections passes the open file handles (sockets) to another already forked thread which is sleeping? (Apache is running in pre-fork mode).

Answer (score 1):

In pre-fork mode there is no single thread accepting connections. The master process binds the listening socket and passes it to the worker processes when forking them (no mystery here, child processes by default inherit the parent's file descriptors). The worker processes then run loops that call accept(). The workers don't need to communicate with each other, the operating system decides which one gets to handle an incoming connection.

Comment: Thanks Joni for response. I Got the point from your answer. Can you please share any useful resource of apache internal working i.e, how it works internally pre-fork and pre-process or source code can be helpful.

Comment: You can see the implementation in prefork.c in Apache source code, it may not be easy to follow though. For example, there can be multiple listening sockets, and the worker processes can be configured to lock a mutex before calling accept.